# Unable to Load Spacy-model on Big Endian system

Tags: python, python-3.x, endianness, spacy

I tested my model on little endian systems like linux and windows, but i am unable to do load my model (tried loading default en_core_web_sm model too) on Big Endian system.

Is spacy Endian neutral, is it tried and tested on Big Endian systems.
Please help. Error given below:

```
>>> nlp=en_test_Demo.load()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user2/app/python352/lib/python3.5/site-packages/en_test_Demo/__init__.py", line 17, in load
    return lang(path=Path(data_dir), **kwargs)
  File "/home/user2/app/python352/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy-1.9.0-py3.5-aix-7.1.egg/spacy/en/__init__.py", line 34, in __init__
    Language.__init__(self, **overrides)
  File "/home/user2/app/python352/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy-1.9.0-py3.5-aix-7.1.egg/spacy/language.py", line 265, in __init__
    if 'vocab' not in overrides \
  File "/home/user2/app/python352/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spacy-1.9.0-py3.5-aix-7.1.egg/spacy/language.py", line 42, in create_vocab
    tag_map=cls.tag_map, lemmatizer=lemmatizer)
  File "spacy/vocab.pyx", line 94, in spacy.vocab.Vocab.load (spacy/vocab.cpp:4974)
  File "spacy/vocab.pyx", line 435, in spacy.vocab.Vocab.load_lexemes (spacy/vocab.cpp:9653)
  File "spacy/strings.pyx", line 146, in spacy.strings.StringStore.__getitem__ (spacy/strings.cpp:2577)
IndexError: 1453852416
>>>
```